# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '118,10028,10029' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Declare @ls_sql nchar(50)
Set @ls_sql='118,10028,10029'

Select * from Accounts Where Accid in(@ls_sql)
```

Error On Executing

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '118,10028,10029' to data type int.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because SQL server expects `(118,10028,10029)` instead of `varchar` value. So it tries to convert `'118,10028,10029'` into INT datatype. You can't use IN operator in this way in T-SQL.

Try to use

```
Select * from Accounts 
Where ','+@ls_sql+',' LIKE '%,'+cast(Accid as VARCHAR(100))+',%'
```